# Listing independent clauses as effects in a conditional sentence

Tags: punctuation, clauses, lists

I have a sentence of the form "If X, A will B and C will D," and there is some disagreement of how to punctuate it.

On one hand, it is a dependent clause followed by two independent clauses connected by a coordinating conjunction. In this case, there should be a comma before the "and"

On the other hand, it is a conditional clause followed by a list of effects. Since there are only two effects, a comma would be unnecessary.

How should the sentence be treated? Which punctuation is correct?

Sources would be especially appreciated.

Here is an example sentence:

> If John goes to the party, Mary will bake a cake (,) and Bob will be unhappy.

Comment: @Rathony I don't get what you don't get? OP specifically said *before* the "and".  Also it is their first question. And asking for a source is a *good* thing, not a bad one! I have put the notional comma in to help people who don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

No comma.

Consider the two options:

```
If John goes to the party, Mary will bake a cake and Bob will be unhappy.

If John goes to the party, Mary will bake a cake, and Bob will be unhappy.
```

Option 2 looks like a **list of three items**: on first glance, it looks like you're telling us that the three things are going to happen.  Option 1 is more obviously a conditional:  it has the form "if X, then Y", where X is *"John goes to the party"* and Y is *"Mary will bake a cake and Bob will be unhappy"*